# Entity Framework 5 stored procedures to non entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

Fairly new to Entity Framework. We are using code first to create our entities with migration scripts (to create the database).

Stored procedures are used to return the data from the database. The procedures are also created within migration scripts.

However, the returned result from the stored procedures doesn't map directly to an entity from our model. All samples we've worked through map to entities which don't really cover our needs.

What is the best method or advise to achieve this?

Create an alternative set of models and somehow map to those from the returned result from the procedures?

Comment: Just create an entity for these procedures, no need to get any more complicated than that.

Comment: when i run my update-database, will it not try to create a table for me based on this entity?

Comment: Only if you add it to your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can register complex models for you stored procedures to map to without them having to be database entities.

In your DbContext you should be overriding the OnModelCreating already and can register your complex models for mapping

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Whatever code you already have here...

    modelBuilder.ComplexType<YourComplexModelHere>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

You can register as many complex models as you want here for mapping stored procedures and functions too, however you may not have navigation properties in the models so they must be flattened classes.